# Change some permissions to mandatory in Facebook iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

My iOS app requires several permissions in order to work. For example I need user_friends or user_birthday. 
When login in my app for the first time, user sees a dialog from facebook where he/she can deactivate several of these permissions, but I need them. In a way that the app doesn't make any sense without that information.
How should I manage that situation?
Is there any way to force that those permissions should be mandatory? And if user doesn't like it, the he/she has to uninstall the app.

Comment: No, you can not force users to accept certain permissions. All you can do is check if they granted them, and if not ask for them again. (How to do that, is described in the docs.)

Answer (score 2):

As CBRoe already said in the comments, you can't force them to accept certain permissions. If your app doesn't work without the information, you should change your registration process a little bit and create some extra views to ask the user_birthday manually (if the user didn't accept to share it on Facebook. Convince them on this view why you need their birthday).

If the concept of your app relies heavily on the user_friends feature, you have to change your concept a little bit. Because since Facebook made API V1.0 of the Facebook SDK deprecated (read as: not usable anymore), you have to use version 2.0 where the user_friends feature is heavily changed. In version 1.0 you would get the whole friendlist, whereas in version 2.0 you get only the friends who are also using the app (and accepted the user_friends permission in Facebook). Tip: maybe some other calls suits your concept such as invitable_friends (only for games), taggable_friends or inviting other friends by using your app (App invites: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/overview)

If you definitely need the information from Facebook, you have to convince the user to give it to you. Which means, create some sort of small introductory on why you need the information.

I would recommend try to change your concept a little bit and make some features optional (I know, this one is difficult). The user can always use your app, but based on the information they gave you access to, some features will be enabled/disabled. Hope this wil clarify some stuff.

Comment: Impossible. Without that info my app doesn't work. Reading docs I guess I could use if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"] and then tell the user I need that data (using a dialog) and then go to login again. So, I guess that's the only possibility :(